# How to use button through border in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

this is my code block

```
<grid>
   <button name="button" click="button_click"/>
   <border background="black" opacity="0.2"/>
</grid>
```

I want to use the button that is under border layer but it's not possible because border has its own tap event
Is there a way to use this button click event when the border is on top of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `IsHitTestVisible` property of your Border to false:

```
<grid>
   <button Name="button" Click="button_click"/>
   <border Background="black" Opacity="0.2" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
</grid>
```